# Comparsion between DCGAN and WGAN

Tags: computer-vision, gan, generative-models

What is the main architectural difference between DCGAN and WGAN?  For which problems each models can be more useful than the other one?

Answer (score 2):

DCGAN is more about *network architecture* alterations, while WGAN is an change to the *loss function*. There's nothing stopping you from using the DCGAN architecture with the WGAN objective function: all this means is minimizing an approximate Wasserstein loss, rather than a Jensen-Shannon divergence, using a particular network architecture. The WGAN (or its followups, e.g. WGAN-GP) objective is agnostic to the architecture. The only thing (that I can think of) that you need to watch for is the use of batch norm: DCGAN recommends putting it everywhere, but (at least for WGAN-GP) it messes with statistics of the critic regularization.

Comment: what grounds make the Wasserstein distance preferable to the Jensen-Shannon divergence in this, and more general, contexts?